# problem using surfraw with helm

Tags: helm, web-browser

I'm fairly new to emacs. I'm using OS X 10.10. I have been learning to use helm. I was interested in [its integration with surfraw](http://tuhdo.github.io/helm-intro.html). I installed surfraw from teh source tarball following the instructions at surfraw.alioth.debian.org.

However, when I use helm-surfraw, I originally got a file not found error. Following [this discussion](http://daemonforums.org/showthread.php?t=8813), I determined this was partly due to lack of a default browser.

I installed lynx as follows:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/src
cd /usr/local/src
sudo curl -O http://lynx.isc.org/lynx2.8.7/lynx2.8.7.tar.gz
sudo tar -xzvf lynx2.8.7.tar.gz
cd lynx2-8-7
sudo ./configure --mandir=/usr/share/man
sudo make
sudo make install
```

Then, I did the following:

```
$ mkdir -p ~/.config/surfraw
$ echo "SURFRAW_text_browser=/usr/local/bin/lynx" >> ~/.config/surfraw/conf
$ echo "SURFRAW_graphical=no" >> ~/.config/surfraw/conf
```

The good news is that I can now run surfraw from the terminal. However, helm-surfraw still doesn't work. I'm not given any options for a search engine (see screenshot).

I'm interested in helm-surfraw alternatives, but I'd also like to understand what I'm doing wrong.

[image]

Comment: "However, helm-surfraw still doesn't work." Can you elaborate?

Comment: Yes: "I'm not given any options for a search engine".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try two twings:

1. Open Terminal and type `surfraw -elvi`. If you get `GLOBAL ELVI:` and nothing else go to next step
2. Install `gnu-sed` from `Mac-Ports`. And relink the new `gnu-sed` with the old one (I think it's located on /usr/bin/sed/)

Comment: I didn't realize that Mac-Ports still existed. A quick search of www.macports.org doesn't reveal a `gnu-sed` though. But why will this help?

Comment: Yes sorry, you should download using homebrew . The problem is connected with sed. OSX has a built in sed which is not recognized by surfraw.

Comment: OK, got that far. I'm not sure what you mean by 'relink' though. There isn't anything in `/usr/bin/sed/`, either. There is a binary file `sed` in /usr/bin/

Comment: If you have installed `gnu-sed` from homebrew you should have two `sed` files one located in `/usr/local/bin/`  installed by homebrew (named `gsed`) and another one in `/usr/bin/` which is the one installed by default on OSX (named `sed`). Now move/rename `sed` in another location.  After that give this command :`sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/gnu-sed/4.2.2/bin/gsed /usr/bin/sed`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked for alternatives as well, here are some: try helm-google for general searches and sx or sos for stackexchange searches. sx uses native api. There are other specialized searches, such as helm-dash to search documentation for over 150 APIs. Search for *engine* or *search* to a list of packages on **MELPA**.